# What Bitcoin Securities / Stock exchanges are around?

Tags: stocks, securities

As a historical user of GLBSE I thought the concept was brilliant. Sadly that did not end well but many more have appeared.

https://btct.co/ appears to be the most popular.

Which other stock exchanges are available and what are their advantages & disadvantages?

Comment: <a href="https://btct.co">BTC Trading Corp.</a> & <a href="https://bitfunder.com">BitFunder</a> seem to both be shut down as of this post.

Answer (score 2):

****UNFORTUNATELY THIS IS ALL OUTDATED NOW, SORRY****

`BTC Trading Corp. - https://btct.co`

Pros: good notifications in email, good analysis of your positions

Cons: always in development, weird UI when new features are added, 24 hour withdrawal limits, but you can request larger amounts but it is delayed a few hours as the admin has to move the bitcoins from cold storage

`BitFunder - https://bitfunder.com`

Pros: looks more advanced than BTC Trading Corp

Cons: stock prices are typically lower there on cross-listed securities, no email notifications when anything happens, lame we-exchange thing

`Havelock Investments - https://havelockinvestments.com`

Pros/Cons: Best UI UX, Canada.

`MPEx - http://mpex.co`

Pros/Cons: Run by a multiple personality lunatic.

Cons: Admission/Listing fees, I forget. Nonexistent UI

Answer (score 1):

**OUTDATED TOO!**

The most popular at this time is indeed btct.co. There are the ones I know of existing.

- BTC Trading Corp. - https://btct.co
- BitFunder - https://bitfunder.com
- Havelock Investments - https://havelockinvestments.com
- MPEx - http://mpex.co

Answer (score 0):

I've used BitFunder I've not used any others so I can't speak to the pros or cons of each.  With BitFunder you have to use WeExchange to transfer your coins to them which is a bit of a pain instead of being able to just deposit directly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using cryptostocks.com for BTC/LTC/DVC denominated 'stocks'. It has a varied selection of companies (with dividend payments and even some rudimentary option writing/trading system), it's easy to use and quite affordable (except for issuing your own shares, which requires a hefty fee). Nothing to complain about so far, but I haven't tried to withdraw funds yet.

EDIT: I've had some success with predictious.com (binary options on real world events), however the volume is frustratingly low.